# How to translate arrays in newest version of i18n?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, internationalization, vue-i18n

Apparently newest versions of vue-i18n (9.9.0+) don't work with arrayed translations.

If I have messages:

```
{
  foo: 'Lorem Ipsum 1',
  bar: ['Lorem Ipsum 2']
}
```

the message which is an Array won't work with `$t` and `i18n.global.t` function:

```
console.log(i18n.global.t('foo')) // returns 'Lorem Ipsum 1' - correct
console.log(i18n.global.t('bar')) // returns 'bar' - incorrect! should return array, like below:
console.log(i18n.global.messages.value[i18n.global.locale.value]['bar'] // returns Proxy(Array) {0: 'Lorem Ipsum 2'}
```

In an older version of I18n `i18n.global.t('bar')` would return the array rather than just the key ("bar").

Why it was changed? What alternatives can we use instead of `i18n.global.t` that apparently doesn't support arrays anymore?

Comment: it's covered in the [v9 migration guide](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/breaking#translation-api-return-value).  use `tm` and `rt` functions if you need to work with arrays and objects.